# In Pandas, how to retrieve the rows which created each group, after aggregation and filtering?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Let

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
        'b': [True, True, True, False, False, True]
    }
)

print(df)

groups = df.groupby('a')  # "A", "B", "C"
agg_groups = groups.agg({'b':lambda x: all(x)}) # "A": True, "B": False, "C": True
agg_df = agg_groups.reset_index()
filtered_df = agg_df[agg_df["b"]]  # "A": True, "C": True

print(filtered_df)


# Now I want to get back the original df's rows, but only the remaining ones after group filtering
```

current output:

```
   a      b
0  A   True
1  A   True
2  B   True
3  B  False
4  B  False
5  C   True
   a     b
0  A  True
2  C  True
```

Required:

```
   a      b
0  A   True
1  A   True
2  B   True
3  B  False
4  B  False
5  C   True
   a     b
0  A  True
2  C  True
   a      b
0  A   True
1  A   True
5  C   True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for get all Trues to mask with same size like original DataFrame, so possible use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('all')]

#alternative
#f = lambda x: x.all()
#df1 = df[df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(f)]
print (df1)
   a     b
0  A  True
1  A  True
5  C  True
```

If want filter in aggregation function output is boolean Series and filter match indices mapped by original column `a`:

```
ids = df.groupby('a')['b'].all()

df1 = df[df.a.isin(ids.index[ids])]
print (df1)
   a     b
0  A  True
1  A  True
5  C  True
```

Your solution is similar with filter column `b`:

```
groups = df.groupby('a')
agg_groups = groups.agg({'b':lambda x: all(x)})

df1 = df[df.a.isin(agg_groups.index[agg_groups['b']])]
print (df1)
   a     b
0  A  True
1  A  True
5  C  True
```

Comment: how can I use a custom lambda instead of `.transform('all')`?

Comment: @Gulzar - I think you need last solution in answer?

Comment: I think so, but a question about performance - it seems to the naked eye that `df.a.isin(agg_groups.index[agg_groups['b']])` runs a search of each `b` in the original index. I thought there is a way in which the groupby object knows the inds it was originated from without searching for it again

Comment: `df[df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: all(x))]`

Comment: @Gulzar - `thought there is a way in which the groupby object knows the inds it was originated from without searching for it again ` - Unfortunately not if use aggregation.

Comment: Trying to apply this to my code, I now see I am grouping by more than one column, which then fails the `isin`. Is there a quick fix?

Comment: [Opened a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75855026/in-pandas-how-to-retrieve-the-rows-which-created-each-group-after-aggregation)

Answer (score 1):

One can filter the original `df` by keeping the rows where the column `a` is present in the column `a` of the `filtered_df` in a variety of ways. Below will leave two potential options.

**Option 1**

As per [OP's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75854693/in-pandas-how-to-retrieve-the-rows-which-created-each-group-after-aggregation#comment133800119_75854718) to use a custom lambda, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as follows

```
final_df = df[df.apply(lambda row: row['a'] in filtered_df['a'].values, axis=1)]

[Out]:

   a      b
0  A   True
1  A   True
5  C   True
```

---

**Option 2**

Another way to solve it is to filtering the original `df` by keeping the rows where the column `a` is present in the column `a` of the `filtered_df`.

For that, one can use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) as follows

```
finaldf = df[df['a'].isin(filtered_df['a'])]

[Out]:

   a      b
0  A   True
1  A   True
5  C   True
```

---

**Notes:**

- There are strong opinions on using `.apply()`. Would recommend reading this: [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869)

Answer (score 0):

`df[df['a'].isin(filtered_df['a'].unique())]`

Results in:

```
   a     b
0  A  True
1  A  True
5  C  True
```

Comment: I am not following why `unique`

Comment: To have a unique list of your grouping criteria. I think the solution using transform posted in jezraels answer is the most useful one. See my comment under his post for a way to use custom lambda functions in transform.